# How Could I Populate a Textarea With a CSS Class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any javascript function that would allow me to display a css class?

Say for example I have the class:

```
.formInput{
   width:100px;
   height:20px;
   border:1px solid #000;
}
```

And I literally wanted to display that class in a textarea... is this possible?
And if not, is there a way of displaying all of the set css properties of an element?

Comment: i overlooked that you are not using jquery , are you using jquery , otherwise also we can get property's in javascript also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: Do you mean "How can I parse my document's stylesheet, find a CSS rule-set with a particular class selector, then get that rule-set as a string which I can place in a textarea?"?

Comment: @david that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Firefox, and kinda works in Chrome:

```
function getCss(className) {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[i].cssRules.length; j++) {
            if (document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].selectorText == "." + className) {
                return document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].cssText;
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

For IE, something along these lines might get you on the right track...

```
var elem = document.getElementById('foo');
var styleInfo = '';
for (var style in elem.currentStyle) {
    styleInfo += style + ": " + elem.currentStyle[style] + "\n";
}
```

Depending on the exact problem you're trying to solve, another possible (hacky) approach is to get the style elements (`document.getElementsByTagName("style")`), and then use a regular expression to search their `innerHTML` for the text you want

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery' attr to get all the propertyz'

```
http://api.jquery.com/attr/
```

you can use .css also to get remaining ones

```
http://api.jquery.com/css/
```

then use jquerys .text or .val to set it to html

```
http://api.jquery.com/val/
```

Comment: your answer a) uses jquery and b) doesn't come close to answering the question

Comment: @Emment , i completly agree with jquery , but second point i don't agree, by using jquerys' attr and css we can get all the property's of html element like what he asked for sure

Comment: but that would require knowing the names of all the attributes and styles in advance

Comment: @Emment his question is not clear , don't know whether he wants to scan the complete page and get all the classes//

Answer (score -1):

you try this you make the effect on textarea with class the style.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.theStyle {

    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
-->
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function makeVis(divID) {
        document.getElementById(divID).style.visibility = "visible";
    }
</script>

<textarea name="id" class="theStyle"  id="in" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea>

<a href="javascript:makeVis('in');">Make One Visible</a>
```

Comment: OP wnats to get the class name of a html element//